# Are there any building blocks for a search engine that will scrape other sites?

Tags: search, search-engine, web-crawler

I want build a search service for one particular thing. The data is freely available out there, via free classified services, and a host of other sites.

Are there any building blocks, e.g. open-source crawlers that I would customize - rather than build from scratch, that I can use?

Any advice on building such a product? Not just technical, but any privacy/legal things that I might need to take into consideration.

E.g. do I need to 'give credit' where the results are from and put a link to the original - if I get them from many places?

Edit: By the way, I am using GWT with JS for the front-end, haven't decided on the language for the back-end. Either PHP or Python. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few blocks in python you can use.

1. beautifulsoup [http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/] for parsing HTML. It can handle bad code too, and its API is veeery easy... way better than any DOM-like tool for me. My friend used it to scrape his old phpbb forum with success. It has pretty good docs.
2. mechanize [http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/] is a webbrowser-simulating http client library. It handles cookies, filling forms and so on. Also easy to use, but it helps if you understand how does http work.
3. http://dev.scrapy.org/ -- this is a relatively new thing: a whole scraping framework based on twisted. I haven't played with it much.

I use first two for my needs; f.e. it needs 20 lines of code to get an automatic testing tool for a 3-stage poll, with simulation of waiting for user entering data and so on.

Comment: So I guess the notion is that I would be creating a 'screen-scraper' and parsing through the HTML code and taking out the useful info, then dumping that into a db? Is that the general process?

Comment: For me it was generic enough... the only limitation I see is that there is neither javascript nor flash engine to fully simulate webbrowser. You can add js with spidermonkey binding though -- I never needed that.

Answer (score 0):

I made a screen-scraper in Ruby that took like five minutes. Apparently [this dude](http://www.igvita.com/2007/02/04/ruby-screen-scraper-in-60-seconds/) has it down to 60 seconds! I'm not sure if Ruby is as scalable or fast as what you're looking for, but I've never seen a faster route to a proof-of-concept or a prototype.

The secret is a library called "[hpricot](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot)", which was built for exactly this purpose.

I don't know anything about PHP or Python or what's available for those development systems/languages.

Good luck!

Comment: So I guess the notion is that I would be creating a 'screen-scraper' and parsing through the HTML code and taking out the useful info, then dumping that into a db?

Is that the general process?